# How to use Puppeteer to download pdf

Tags: node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I'm trying to do a bit of web scraping using Puppeteer, but I'm not sure how to actually download the documents I find. Specifically, I want to download the pdf from a page like [this](https://dcr.alleghenycounty.us/Wills/Search/DOCUMENTS/WRV1160000053A.pdf). The part of my code that's trying to download the pdf currently looks like this (commented lines being download attempts that didn't work):

```js
const newPagePromise = new Promise(x =>
  browser.once("targetcreated", target => x(target.page()))
);
await page.click(
  "#gvDocketResult_ctl0" + rows.length + "_hlDocumentRedacted"
);
await page.waitFor(3000);
const newPage = await newPagePromise;
// need to figure out how to download
await newPage._client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
  behavior: "allow",
  downloadPath: "/Users/me/Desktop",
});
// await newPage.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'letter'});
// await newPage.click('#download');
// await newPage.click('#icon');
```

From what I've found so far it seems like if I can get the link shown in the `src = ''` section of the webpage (image below) then I might be able to use a page.goto(link) to download the pdf? In any case I have no idea how to get to that link in puppeteer, so if anyone has advice on that it would also be appreciated. [image]

Comment: So this doesn't work at the moment, does it? BTW, what's puppeteer version?

Answer (score 0):

You can download file by direct link with streams.

```js
const https = require('https');

const fileUrl = await page.$eval('#plugin', file => file.src);
https.get(fileUrl, res => {
  stream = fs.createWriteStream('file.pdf');
  res.pipe(stream);
  stream.on('error', (err)=>{
     console.error(err);
  })
  stream.on('finish', () => {
     stream.close();
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const your_url = " put your url here "

const page2 = await browser.newPage()

const dir='C:/the directory you want to place the file';

const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()
await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: path.resolve(dir)});

async function downloadFile(page, link) {                                                                                                                    
     
    return page.evaluate((link) =>
   {  
      location.href = link;
   
    },link);                                                                                                                    
}

downloadFile(page2,your_url)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.